# PDO query splits SQL column into an array of characters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When querying my local database for a single column, rather than returning an array of rows, it returns a multidimensional array with each string split into separate characters.

[image]

The PDO query:

```
$hostname = '127.0.0.1';
$username = 'db_user';
$password = 'db_pass';
$dbname = 'db_name';
$port = '8889';

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname;port=$port", $username, $password);

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT answers FROM table_name');

$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetch();

echo $results[0][1];
```

This returns 'm' rather than the entire string. I've tried using fetchAll, fetchColumn, fetch(PDO:FETCH_COLUMN) to similar results. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking the arrays one step too far in

```
echo $results[0][1];
```

When you call `fetch()`, this returns an array of the values from a single row of the select, so in your case as you are only fetching `answers`, this will mean that `$results[0]` will contain the value in column `answers`.  When you use `$results[0][1]` you are saying to fetch the second character of the string in `$results[0]` (as this is a string [] refers to each character as though the string is an array).

If you write instead

```
echo $results[0];
```

You should get the full column.

If you use `fetchAll()` - this should give you the results your after as it returns an array of all of the rows.  But, as arrays are 0 based, you should use

```
echo $results[0][0];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I do either of these it returns undefined rather than the row

Comment: So just changing `$results[0][1]` to `$results[0]` gives undefined (keeping it as `fetch()`)?

Comment: Yes that and `$results[0][0]` with `fetchAll()` both return undefined

Comment: What does `print_r($results)` with just `fetch()` give.

Comment: OK, I just figured it out and I believe the undefined error was caused by invalid json being passed when I returned the results using ajax, rather than an issue with the PDO query. Appreciate the help though.